# C++14 variadic template argument inference in clang and gcc

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, c++14, clang++

I am using clang 3.5.0 and gcc version 4.9.2 (both with C++14 options on, although with trailing return types this could be done in C++11).

The following code compiles in g++ and not in clang++.  My question is "which is right?"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

template<typename OP, typename F1, typename... Fs>
struct symop {
     OP op;
     tuple<F1,Fs...> fs;

     symop(const OP &oopp, const F1 &f1, const Fs &...ffss)
          : op(oopp), fs(f1,ffss...) {}
};

template<typename OP, typename... Fs>
auto baz(const symop<OP,Fs...> &so) {
     return so.op(get<0>(so.fs),get<1>(so.fs));
}

/* // this version compiles on both compilers
template<typename OP, typename F1, typename... Fs>
auto baz(const symop<OP,F1,Fs...> &so) {
     return so.op(get<0>(so.fs),get<1>(so.fs));
}
*/

int main() {
     symop<plus<int>,int,int> so{plus<int>{},3,4};
     cout << baz(so) << endl;
}
```

Clang reports

```
q.cpp:29:10: error: no matching function for call to 'baz'
        cout << baz(so) << endl;
                ^~~
q.cpp:16:6: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument
      'OP'
auto baz(const symop<OP,Fs...> &so) {
     ^
```

Comment: It's a bug in Clang, [fixed with Clang 3.6](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1405db5825284b1d)

Comment: Ah.. Thanks.  My search-foo wasn't good enough to find this.

Comment: It's always a good idea to check with the newest versions of the compilers. http://melpon.org/wandbox/ is great for that purpose.

Answer (score -2):

You should understand that Clang is still experimental (even though it is "widely" used), and basically is built upon GCC (trough it has some significant changes) and you can be sure that everything (talking C++ code) that is compiled in GCC should compile in Clang, and if not, it is a Clang bug.

GCC had it's time to prove being robust.

Comment: quote from http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html: `Clang fully implements all published ISO C++ standards including C++11, as well as the upcoming C++14 standard, and some parts of the fledgling C++1z standard, and is considered a production-quality C++ compiler`

Comment: `you can be sure that everything (talking C++ code) that is compiled in GCC should compile in Clang, and if not, it is a Clang bug.` So **not true**. See all the bug reports of both g++ and clang regarding corner cases in c++ language.

Comment: What have you been drinking? The "built over gcc" bit is especially hilarious - the very point of the Clang project was to build a new C++ front-end completely from scratch because the architecture of gcc was showing its serious limitations. Also, Clang normally  uses LLVM as a backend, so not even the backend is in common.

Comment: @Matteo Italia: you might get me wrong. the meaning of "built over gcc" stands for  -> clang is designed to be compatible with GCC and eventually replace it (in ideology).

Comment: @bolov: by the case of irony, you are in a question page with confirmed clang bug.